A question about an algebraic relation in a splitting field

Example. Let $F = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $K = F(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1$. This polynomial has no roots in $F$, as a quick calculation shows, so it is irreducible over $F$ and $[K: F] = 3$. The field $K$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, and the roots of $f$ are $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, and $\alpha^4$, by Corollary 6.9. Since $f(\alpha) = 0$, we see that $\alpha = \alpha^2 + 1$, so $\alpha^4 = \alpha^3 + \alpha = \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1$. Therefore, in terms of the basis $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$ for $K/F$, the roots of $f$ are $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, and $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2$. This shows explicitly that $F(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$.

I would like to ask that why $\alpha^3 = \alpha^2 + 1$ in this example? I think if $\alpha$ is a root of of $f(x)$ then $\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1 = 0$. How can conclude the previous equation?

In characteristic $2$, saying $\alpha^3=-\alpha^2-1$ is the same as saying $\alpha^3=\alpha^2+1$.

The OP should also ask why "Since $f(\alpha)=0$, we see that $\alpha=\alpha^2+1$" in the example quoted by the OP makes any sense, especially when it is followed by what seems to be a non sequitur  $\alpha^4=\alpha^3 +\alpha$.

@Dilip, no doubt a typo, should be $\alpha^3=\alpha^2+1$, but we don't know whether the typo is due to OP or due to the unnamed source OP is quoting.

@GerryMyerson Yes, of course it is a typo, and I agree that we don't know whether it is due to the OP while transcribing the source, or is present in the source the OP is quoting.

@lulu Seems to be an answer, not a comment.
